# Multi-dimentional array question: Where does ['children'] come from?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am confused about multi-dimentional array.

In the following db, php and html, I don't understand the usage of

```
foreach ($navlist as $key => $list){
foreach ($list as $topkey => $toplist){..

and

foreach ($toplist['children'] as $subkey => $subname){...
```

And also this code is confusing for me. Is ['children'] php?

```
$data[0][$row->parentid]['children'][$row->id] = $row->name;
```

I will appreciate if you can explain this navgation.php

Thanks in advance.

I have the followings in db.

```
INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `shortdesc`, `longdesc`, `status`, `parentid`)  
VALUES (1, 'shoes', 'Shoes for boys and girls.', '', 'active', 7);
INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `shortdesc`, `longdesc`, `status`, `parentid`) 
VALUES (2, 'shirts', 'Shirts and blouses!', '', 'active', 7);
[...]
INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `shortdesc`, `longdesc`, `status`, `parentid`)     
VALUES (9, 'test', 'testing', 'Testing!!!!', 'inactive', 0);
```

Model has the following php

```
function getCategoriesNav(){
     $data = array();
     $this->db->select('id,name,parentid');
     $this->db->where('status', 'active');
     $this->db->orderby('parentid','asc');
     $this->db->orderby('name','asc');
     $this->db->groupby('parentid,id');
     $Q = $this->db->get('categories');
     if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
       foreach ($Q->result() as $row){
            if ($row->parentid > 0){
                $data[0][$row->parentid]['children'][$row->id] = $row->name;

            }else{
                $data[0][$row->id]['name'] = $row->name;
            }
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result(); 
    return $data; 
 }
```

And controller/navigation.php

```
  if (count($navlist)){
  echo "<ul>";
  foreach ($navlist as $key => $list){
    foreach ($list as $topkey => $toplist){
        echo "<li class='cat'>";
        echo anchor("welcome/cat/$topkey",$toplist['name']);
        echo "</li>\n";
        if (count($toplist['children'])){
            foreach ($toplist['children'] as $subkey => $subname){
                echo "\n<li class='subcat'>";
                echo anchor("welcome/cat/$subkey",$subname);    
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
    }
  }
  echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

This will produce the following html

```
<ul>
    <li class='cat'>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter_shopping/welcome/cat/7" title="clothes">
            clothes
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        ...
    </li>
    <li class='subcat'>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter_shopping/welcome/cat/5" title="toys">
            toys
        </a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic construct is this:

```
foreach ($navlist as $key => $list)
```

This means iterate through the array `$navlist`, and for each time in `$navlist`, with key `$key` and value `$list`, execute the body of the `foreach` loop.

A simpler example might help.

```
$numbers = array();
$numbers[0] = "Zero";
$numbers[1] = "One";
$numbers[2] = "Two";

foreach($numbers as $number => $text) {
    echo $number." is written ".$text."\n";
}
```

The output of that (unless I've screwed up somewhere), is:

```
0 is written Zero
1 is written One
2 is written Two
```

The code you've given then just has multiple nested loops, so `$list` in the outermost for-loop is itself an associative array, which is then looped through, and the values stored in that associative array are also arrays.

You might find reading the [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) documentation instructive.